# Error to create object of GoogleApiClient, gives java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0

Tags: java, google-api, illegalstateexception

I want to implement autocomplete place google API in android. To do that I need to create an object of GoogleApiClient. I have used the following code for this...

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0 /* clientId */, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

But when the fragment starts, it throws the following exception and the app is  crashed.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient
>   with id 0

**Note: this is performed in FRAGMENT.**

Following is the manifest file configuration..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.example.bluehorsesoftkol.ekplatevendor.Utils.EkPlateVendorApplication">


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bluehorsesoftkol.ekplatevendor.activity.registration.ActivitySplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bluehorsesoftkol.ekplatevendor.activity.registration.ActivityLogin"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.vendor.ActivityHome"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity         android:name="com.example.bluehorsesoftkol.ekplatevendor.activity.vendor.ActivityAddVendor"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.vendor.CustomGalleryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ekplatevendor.ACTION_PICK" />
                <action android:name="ekplatevendor.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/TEST_API_KEY"/>

    </application>
```

So, please help to solve this issue..

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

try this in your code

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage((Activity) context);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Note: from playstore version 10 you dont have to use

`mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage((Activity) context);`

as it will taken care by library it self.

Comment: Still get same error, can you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037170/google-api-client-already-managing-with-id-0) please @Ravi

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it for my Fragment:

Code for the fragment:

```
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocaitonRequest();
}

private void createLocaitonRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

onStart for the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

onDestroy for the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

I run the **buildGoogleApiClient()** method in **onCreate()**

Then I use a MapView in my XML for my fragment as follows:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map" />
```

Then in my fragment when **onCreateView** I do the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setupMapsFragment(mView);

    mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    if (mMapView != null) {
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    return mView;
}
```

If the navigation is made with a navigationdrawer I did get your problem when I loaded the fragment and then pressed the navigation menu item again and then it crashed so to solve that i did this:

```
if (id == R.id.nav_map) {

        if(checkMapsFragment == true){
            Toast.makeText(this,"map is already loaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(checkMapsFragment == false){
            fragment = new MapsFragment();
            checkMapsFragment = true;
        }
```