# Google Api Client already managing with id 0

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api-client

I want to connect `GoogleApiClient` in activity. It works fine when user click button first time and this dialog appears but when user press back button and reclick the button that responsable for initializing `GoogleApiClient`, I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0
```

[image: Google Api Client Dialog]

Here is my `GoogleApiClient` implementation

```
 private fun initGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
        .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
        .addScope(Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
        .build()
     }

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mGoogleApiClient?.let {
        if (!it.isConnected) it.connect()
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mGoogleApiClient?.let {
        it.stopAutoManage(this)
        if (it.isConnected) it.disconnect()
    }
}

override fun onConnected(bundle: Bundle?) {
    Timber.d("onConnected")
}

override fun onConnectionSuspended(p0: Int) {
    Timber.d("onConnectionSuspended")
}

override fun onConnectionFailed(connectionResult: ConnectionResult) {
    Timber.d("onConnectionFailed")
}
```

Call `initGoogleApiClient` method when user press button

```
btnApiClient.setOnClickListener {
        initGoogleApiClient()
}
```

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105118/error-in-fragment-already-managing-a-googleapiclient-with-id-0) and add `stopAutoManage` method but still get same error. Also checked [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#stopAutoManage(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)) and it says

```
public abstract void stopAutoManage (FragmentActivity lifecycleActivity)
Disconnects the client and stops automatic lifecycle management. Use this before creating a new client (which might be necessary when switching accounts, changing the set of used APIs etc.).

This method must be called from the main thread.
```

So I change my `initGoogleApiClient` method and add `stopAutoManage` method before init but this time nothing happens after first click

```
private fun initGoogleApiClient() {

mGoogleApiClient?.stopAutoManage(this)

mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
    .addScope(Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
    .build()

}
```

Also I have only got this two dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

Any help will be appriciated